# Learners in CNTK C# API

Tags: c#, python, cntk

I am using C# CNTK 2.2.0 API for training.
I have installed Nuget package CNTK.CPUOnly and CNTK.GPU.

I am looking for following learners in C#.
1. AdaDelta
2. Adam
3. AdaGrad
4. Neterov

Looks like Python supports these learners but C#
package is not showing them.

I can see only SGD and SGDMomentun learners in C# there.

Any thoughts, how to get and set other learners in C#.
Do I need to install any additional package to get these learners?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CNTKLib class in the CNTK namespace provides several learners, even not all of those you have listed. I list them in the following without their overloads.

```
public static Learner SGDLearner(ParameterVector parameters, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble learningRateSchedule);
public static Learner MomentumSGDLearner(ParameterVector parameters, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble learningRateSchedule, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble momentumSchedule);
public static Learner FSAdaGradLearner(ParameterVector parameters, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble learningRateSchedule, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble momentumSchedule);
public static Learner AdamLearner(ParameterVector parameters, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble learningRateSchedule, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble momentumSchedule);
public static Learner AdaGradLearner(ParameterVector parameters, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble learningRateSchedule);
public static Learner RMSPropLearner(ParameterVector parameters, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble learningRateSchedule, double gamma, double inc, double dec, double max, double min);
public static Learner AdaDeltaLearner(ParameterVector parameters, TrainingParameterScheduleDouble learningRateSchedule);
```

You easily can access them like the following:

```
using CNTK;
CNTKLib.AdaDeltaLearner([...])
```

This was done with the GPU version of CNTK 2.2. Maybe it is different with the CPU version.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks. This helps.  Yes, I can see them in CPUOnly library as well.    Python provides Nesterov learner. Is this missing in C#?

Comment: these are all of the learners provided via C# at the moment. Perhaps more will come with newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Download the NCCL 2 app to configure in c# www.nvidia. com or google NCCL download

Comment: Thanks. NCCL is only providing the GPU acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Checked that CNTKLib is providing those learners in CPUOnly package.
Nestrov is missing in there but present in python.

There is a difference while creating the trainer object 
with CNTKLib learner function vs Learner class.

If a learner class is used, 
net parameters are provided as a IList.
This can be obtained using netout.parameter() ;

If CNTKLib is used, 
parameters are provided as ParameterVector. 
Build ParameterVector while building the network.
and provide it while creating Trainer object.

ParameterVector pv = new ParameterVector ()

pv.Add(weightParameter)

pv.Add(biasParameter)

Thanks everyone for your answers.